# Listing Cluster of Differentiation (CD) markers (immunology)

Tags: immunology, publishing

I hope this question is appropriate for this SE. When listing multiple cluster of differentiation (CD) markers to define a cell population, e.g. CD3+CD8+CD45+CD4-, is there a default order to put them in? I was recently told to list them numerically with the negative populations after the positive ones (i.e. CD3+CD8+CD45+CD4-). However, I have seen different orders in the literature and would personally prefer to order them by whatever I would consider most logical (e.g. CD45+CD3+CD8+CD4-).

Comment: There is no convention like that AFAIK.

Comment: WYSIWYG is correct, and I would tend to agree with your personal preference - order the markers in the manner that makes the most sense, not necessarily in any numerical or positive/negative order.